# Way to keep template inference in C++03 with function objects?

Tags: c++, templates, functional-programming

I would like to provide a (templated) function taking (among other) a function-ish object with a given return type as an argument, and ideally I would like to be able to call that function without explicit template arguments.

So far I tried:

```
template<A, B, F>
B some(A a, F f) { return f(a); }

template<A, B>
B some(A a, B (*f)(A)) { return some<A, B, B (*)(A)>(a, f); }
```

Where I have the overload to make the template args fully inferable, at least for function pointers. Now it seems I can't make the template specialization for `std::unary_function`, since it doesn't contain the `operator()` member and so it is not suitable as `F`.

Moreover, it seems there isn't any solution for functors in general, since I can't inform the compiler that I want F to have `B operator()(A)`. Or is such duck typing possible somehow?

Comment: `boost::function1` (or `N` in general) eases the pain a little since it at least provides `operator()` and various functionish objects can be converted to it, so the `F` template arg is not needed. But not everyone can use `boost` and the occassional conversion might get ugly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`std::unary_function` is just a base for other classes with should provide `operator()`. There should be no instances of `unary_function` at all, so I can't see the problem - the first function taking 3 template arguments is the official solution for such problems.

edit: If you wanna call that function without explicit template arguments, than use `std::result_of` (C++11) or `boost::result_of`.

Comment: Sure, but then I must explicitly supply template arguments, which I would like to avoid.

Comment: In C++11 you can use result_of, but in C++03... let me think. You can try to implement result_of using typeof, but that's a hack. I don't know if that will work. edit: look at this http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/boost/utility/result_of.hpp

Comment: Great! I changed to `template<typename A, typename F> typename boost::result_of<F(A)>::type some(A a, F f) { ... }` and I can call it without template args just as I wanted. Could you include it in you answer to accept?